# How to get SQL output with more rows than original table? - Timeline of Events

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, case, window-functions

I have a table as follows:

```
event_num    occurs_at_time     length
1            0                  10
2            10                 3
3            20                 10
4            30                 5
```

Intended output:

```
start_time     length      event_type
0              10          Occurrence
10             3           Occurrence
13             7           Free Time
20             10          Occurrence
30             5           Occurrence
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to create a new row for `Free Time` in a `SELECT` statement. `Free Time` events occur whenever the difference between the next row `occurs_at_time` and previous row `length` + `occurs_at_time` is > 0.

For instance, between `event_num` 2 and `event_num` 3, `20 - 10 - 3 = 7` is the `length` and `10 + 3 = 13` will be the `start_time`.

I tried using `LAG()` and `LEAD()` window functions with `CASE WHEN` clauses to compare the next and previous rows, but I'm not sure how I can create a new row in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below

```
select * from (
  select occurs_at_time as start_time, 
    length, 
    'Occurrence' as event_type
  from your_table
  union all
  select occurs_at_time + length as start_time, 
    lead(occurs_at_time) over(order by occurs_at_time) - occurs_at_time - length as length, 
    'Free Time' event_type
  from your_table
)
where length > 0
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]